# How to list all languages in correct order and switch to a language-specific URL?

Tags: hugo, static-site

I'm using Hugo 0.40.1 https://gohugo.io/ on Ubuntu, and trying to create a language switch control using the following code:

```
{{ range $.Site.Languages }}
    <span href="#"> {{ .Lang }} - {{ .LanguageName }} </span>
{{ end }}
```

Where the **config.yaml** file contains the following:

```
languages:
  en:
    weight: 1
    LanguageName: english
  es:
    weight: 2
    LanguageName: español
  fr:
    weight: 3
    LanguageName: français
```

There are the following problems with this:

1. no matter what variables/expressions I'm trying, I cannot display 
   the **.LanguageName** - 
   either an empty string is displayed, or the current page language
   name is repeated all over; note that **.Lang** works correctly - but
   nothing else
2. according to the documentation, **$.Site.Languages** is supposed to work 
   in the order specified by **weight**, but does not work like
   that and languages are not ordered in any predictable way
3. it is unclear (from the documentation) how to construct URLs pointing 
   to different languages of the current page

I'm trying to post it here as well as on GitHub, in attempt to find somebody who implemented something similar in the past with Hugo.

Answer (score 3):

The discussion forum of Hugo was very helpful and eventually I've figured out the solution. See this link for details:
[this question in the Hugo discussion forum](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/solved-problem-listing-languages-in-a-correct-order-and-switching-to-a-language-specific-page-url/)

```
{{ range $.AllTranslations }}
    <a class='{{if eq .Lang $.Lang}} selected {{end}}' href='{{.RelPermalink}}'> {{ .Language.LanguageName }} </a>
{{ end }}
```

My main mistake was using Site.Languages where I had to use Translations or AllTranslations.

Not sure what was the problem with the order and the LanguageName because at some moment it just "started working".